# How to read Bytes of an Image in Java?

Tags: java, image, inputstream, javax.imageio, fileoutputstream

I am currently working with Image processing in Java. Initially I used ImageIO class to write images

```
ImageIO.write(image,"jpg",os);
```

the problem with this method is am lossing the actual image size and quality. Then I preferred ByteStream

```
Files.readAllBytes(fi.toPath());
```

to read and

```
fos.write(fileContent);
```

to write Images. This works perfectly. The issue I am facing here is I can read only files but not Images(ie, BuffreredImage image). Is it possible to read a Image rather than files here or should I move to someother IO?

Code Snippet is here,

```
try {

File fnew=new File("d:\\3\\IMG1.jpg"); 
java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(new             File("d:\\3\\Test1\\4.jpg"));
File fi = new File("d:\\3\\7.jpg");
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(fi.toPath());
fos.write(fileContent);

} catch (Exception e) {

System.out.println("Exception");
}
```

Any Kind of suggestions or help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: My Input type is Images only not files. :-(

Comment: you can edit the question and add extra details

Comment: @ Laxman - I am processing Images (Reading Images, changing quality, resizing it, setting watermarks and finally writing it in destination). Issue is If i use ImageIO.write() then am  lossing the actual image quality when i write. so I moved to FileOutputStream and read byte[]. My question is is there any possibility to read bytes of an Image when input is an Image or should I go with other IO?

Comment: @J_User Reading the image is not the problem. Using different IO will not help. It is the conversion between Bitmap and JPEG that is killing the quality.

Comment: @Navin I am getting JPEG images only as my input. I dont change its format anywhere on my process. Does ImageIO.write() change the image format?

Comment: @J_User Yes, when you read with `ImageIO`, it converting the JPEG to a Bitmap automatically. A JPEG is difficult to edit directly so this is necessary.

Comment: @J_User: What are your requirements? What are you trying to achieve? Do you have access to the original files, or do you receive (from some external system perhaps) the images already decoded? Why do you think you have to write images as JPEG? And: Please update the question with this information, rather than answering in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem with this method is am lossing the actual image size and quality. Then I preferred ByteStream

When you read a JPEG with with ImageIO, it is converting the JPEG to a Bitmap automatically. Then when you write it, it is encoding to a JPEG again (which loses quality).

Just replace `ImageIO.write(image,"jpg",os)` with `ImageIO.write(image,"png",os)` and you are done. A lossless format such as PNG will not lose any data when you write the image.

Comment: My output file should the JPEG. Thats the Issue. Lossless jpg file writing is not possible in ImageIO.write(), I guess..!

Comment: @J_User If lossless JPEG is not supported, you must use another library. Why do you need JPEG? It is practically the *worst* image format.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedImage getRGB() will get you all the actual pixel data for the image.  There will be no compression or anything like JPEG.  It will be the raw image.

Edited to add an example based on my comments...

```
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("google.jpg"));
    ImageWriter w = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpg").next();
    ImageOutputStream out = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("output.jpg"));
    w.setOutput(out);
    ImageWriteParam param = new JPEGImageWriteParam(Locale.getDefault());
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(1);
    w.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
    out.close();
```

Comment: A JPEG file does not store RGB pixels though. There will be some error from the DCT. He has to use a lossless format when writing the image.

Comment: If quality is the only concern (not raw data), you'd use ImageIO to get an ImageWriter, then use ImageWriterParam to set the quality.

Comment: As I wrote in another comment to a (now deleted?) answer, there's no way to write JPEG without some loss in quality. If the original was a JPEG, you could in theory get near-lossless re-compression by using the exact same huffman tables.

Comment: There is lossless JPEG, it's just not part of the standard JDK. 3rd party libraries support it.  That said, the code above with quality set to 100% is pretty darn close.

Comment: No, you will only produce large files. The quality will still be worse than the original, unless the original was compressed with the same tables (unlikely).  JPEG-Lossless or JPEG-LS would work, but that is somewhat artificial, as these are completely different algorithms with less tool support, and probably defeats the purpose of using JPEG in the first place. Just go with PNG or TIFF. :-)

Comment: @Navin and HaraldK Sorry, this is completely irrelevant quest. Is it possible to find  the byte[] of an image directly? Since am not reading any file(image) from disk or any location. Am receiving images as BufferedImage . Attempting to read its bytes and trying something differently.

Comment: I just tested the code above with a 5472x3648 image from a DLSR.  While the file size did increase, the quality did not change at all.  I ran the process 5 times, using previous output as each next input.  Then, I opened the original input and final output in stacked applications (windows photo viewer) and used alt tab.  The images were indistinguishable from each other.  The file size went from 5.2M to 8.4M.

Comment: @J_User, as my original answer stated, use getRGB() to read the bytes directly.  The images is not stored as a JPEG internally, so the bytes you get (from getRGB) will not be in any compressed format.  You can easily use the code above to write to a temp file or memory buffer then read it back out in JPEG format.